# How can I improve my voice?

Tags: voice

I am a 16 year old male and my voice sounds horrible, I mean still better than average but still I find it terrible, so I would like to know if I can still train it at this age or is it too late because I'm old now. To be precise, my objective is to be able to land higher notes and for my voice to sound better for the ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a singing teacher I can tell you as have the other contributors, that you are not old!! Your physical body is still growing and fully shaping and that includes your larynx.

I liken learning to sing to training for a marathon. Both involve training muscles groups that have otherwise only be used for 'normal' day-to-day activities, both involve learning techniques to get the best from these muscles and both require you to gain stamina in using these muscles.

I teach the anatomy of the larynx and HOW we create sound before I then continue teaching further technique as this is absolutely crucial. In most cases, if you can speak, you can learn to sing. It's about muscle recognition, muscle memory, ear-training and practice!

Teaching someone to sing, understanding technique and anatomy is different to then building on this by teaching a specific style (like in your case the singing of the Quran).

I have students of all ages from 7-70, so 16 is not at all too old.

Knowledge and understanding, and then practice really is the key.

I hope this helps and happy vocal journey.

Shout up if you want any more clarification.

Comment: Anecdotally, I sang as an amateur from the age of 7 & as a pro from 19 ..yet still,  my voice didn't really do exactly what I wanted it to do every time, until I reached about 30. There's a long way to go yet; keep practising, it's worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

You're 16. Presumably, you just recently completed the change of voice that comes with puberty.  You're at the age where many many successful musicians started in their first bands. You're NOT OLD! And if you're serious about improving your voice, find a good vocal teacher in the style you want to sing, let him or her show you the correct technique so you don't wreck your vocal cords, and then practice.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is still a problem. There is no teacher, at least none that teaches the style i want. I am a muslim and we "sing" the quran. Except the only peoplr who teach that will only show you how to pronouce the arzbic words and nlt how to song good doing that. Im sorry i didnt mention it earlier but since I was talking strictly about the voice i thougt it wasnt necessary. But what you gave me is good advice nevertheless

Comment: Does your interpretation of Islam forbid you to sing music that is not religious? If not, and there's no teacher nearby, I'd recommend looking for a teacher who offers online lessons (through Skype or whatnot) and learn general singing skills from them, which you can then apply to the quran singing.

Comment: My interpretation of Islam does not forbid me from singing as long as it does not contain swearing etc.. Thats actually a pretty good idea, I am a bit scared but i guess that would do, i am not sure if my parent will accept it but still thank you